# What do hashmarks for a partition shown in diskmgmt.msc mean?

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, disk-management

What does it mean that a partition has hash marks on it for Windows 10?

[image]

Comment: It is simply a design decision, isn't it?

Comment: Hatch marks????

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That simply indicates the partition that currently has attention.  If you use your mouse to click on the **C:** partition, it will have those same marks.  Then, you can potentially right-click and choose another function, like viewing *Properties*.

[image: Disk Management]

Answer (score 11):

#### What does it mean when a partition has hash marks on it in Windows?

It indicates that the partition has been **selected** (also indicated shown by the blue rectangle in the top part of the dialog where a selection is made.).

Here is an example showing the default selection after opening Disk Management:

[image]

After selecting "Expansion (F:)":

[image]

You can see the diagonal lines have moved.

Comment: This has been the case since the original version of Windows NT, version 3.1, so you probably shouldn't imply that your answer is limited to Windows 10. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Answer updated :)